# How to use AnyEvent::JSONRPC together with Perl/Tk

Tags: perl, client-server, tk-toolkit, json-rpc

I'm trying to use [`AnyEvent::JSONRPC::TCP::Server`](https://metacpan.org/pod/AnyEvent%3a%3aJSONRPC%3a%3aTCP%3a%3aServer) to run a server in a [`Perl/Tk`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Tk/Tk.pod) application, which I can send requests to from a [`AnyEvent::JSONRPC::TCP::Client`](https://metacpan.org/pod/AnyEvent%3a%3aJSONRPC%3a%3aTCP%3a%3aClient). I have melted down what I want to do to these two simple server/client scripts:

Server:

```
use AnyEvent::JSONRPC::TCP::Server;

my $server = AnyEvent::JSONRPC::TCP::Server->new( port => 4123 );
$server->reg_cb(
    echo => sub {
        my ($res_cv, @params) = @_;
        print STDERR "echo() called with params ".join(",",@params)."\n";
        $res_cv->result(@params);
    }
);

use Tk;
my $mw = MainWindow->new(-title => "Server is running");
my $ex = $mw->Button(-text => "   Exit the Server   ",
                     -command => sub {exit;})->pack();
MainLoop;
```

and the respective client:

```
use AnyEvent::JSONRPC::TCP::Client;

my $client = AnyEvent::JSONRPC::TCP::Client->new(
    host => '127.0.0.1',
    port => 4123,
);

use Tk;
my $mw = MainWindow->new(-title => "Client is running");
my $ec = $mw->Button(-text => "   Call Echo   ", -command =>
    sub {
      my $res = $client->call( echo => 'foo bar' )->recv();
      print STDERR "Called echo() remotely, got back '$res'\n";
    }
  )->pack();

my $ex = $mw->Button(-text => "   Exit the Client   ",
                     -command => sub {exit;})->pack();
MainLoop;
```

In my Win32 environment I first start the server from one command shell, which gives me the main window and then I start the client from another command shell, which also seems to start up fine with another window.

The problem is: The client can't connect to the server. After some second it says:

```
Tk::Error: Client got error: Failed to connect 127.0.0.1:4123: A connection attempt
    failed because  the connected party did not properly respond after a period of
    time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to
    respond. at C:/Perl5.16/site/lib/AnyEvent/Socket.pm line 998.
 [\&AnyEvent::Impl::Tk::__ANON__]
 ("after" script)
```

As I start the server on the same machine as the client, I think the 'localhost' IP address 127.0.0.1 used in the client code should find the server, right?
As I'm not very deep into network programming, I'm lost here.

Does anyone have an idea, how I could start to debug this? Or does someone even know right away that I'm doing something completely wrong.

Btw.: I'm running ActiveState Perl 5.16.3 on a Windows 7 machine. I want to use JSON RPC because it was recommended for use with Python based solutions when interfacing to Perl.

Thanks!

Comment: The small amount of reading I've done suggests that AnyEvent is supposed to "detect" TK *if you `use TK` first -- then it should automatically incorporate TK's eventloop into its own. I'd have thought that this means you should use the event pumping options in `AnyEvent` from that point (rather than `MainLoop`) -- look for examples... but... I have no idea what `AnyEvent::JSONRPC::TCP::Client` does and whether it has been written to cooperate nicely with others in that respect.